# Missing Internet Connection Icon on my toolbar

Tags: icons, media-buttons

I have no internet icons or buttons in the toolbar at the top of my screen.  I cannot figure out which Internet connections I am using because I don't have that icon/button and I cannot find it anywhere else.

Where are they hidden and how do I put them there?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` command.

Answer (score 1):

Right click a Panel hover your mouse over panel click on panel preferences. click on the items tab click on the green + button Search for `Indicator Plugin` select it and click add.

Comment: This will not work with unity.